# Construct hash by using two arrays Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have two array's as follows:

```
["first_name", "last_name", "email_id",  "company"]
["Andy", "Martin", "hello@ex.com",  nil]
```

I need to construct this as hash as like this.

```
{"first_name"=>"Andy", "last_name"=>"Martin", "email_id"=>"hello@ex.com", "company"=>nil}
```

Is it possible in Ruby? If, then how to do that?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Google zip method

Comment: It works well in irb, but not in my project. It gets constructed in this way..
{["first_name", "last_name", "email_id", "company"]=>["Andy", "Martin", "hello@ex.com", nil]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do this using [**`Array#zip`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
h1 = ["first_name", "last_name", "email_id",  "company"]
h2 = ["Andy", "Martin", "hello@ex.com",  nil]

p Hash[h1.zip(h2)]

# >> {"first_name"=>"Andy", "last_name"=>"Martin", "email_id"=>"hello@ex.com",    "company"=>nil}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't know about the `zip` method, I was just about to suggest using a `for` loop, but this way is much better

Comment: But this constructs this way:
{["first_name", "last_name", "email_id", "company"]=>["Andy", "Martin", "hello@ex.com", nil]}

Comment: @Dinesh I didn't get you.. sorry :) The code is working... Is this not for you?

Answer (score 0):

Even this works for me

```
h1 = ["first_name", "last_name", "email_id",  "company"]
h2 = ["Andy", "Martin", "hello@ex.com",  nil]

Hash[[h1,h2].transpose]

# >> {"first_name"=>"Andy", "last_name"=>"Martin", "email_id"=>"hello@ex.com",    "company"=>nil}
```